# Powershell Foreach-Object with if statement not working - help!

Tags: scripting, powershell

I have a batch file that takes a computer name as its  argument and will install Java JRE on it remotely. Now, Im trying to run this Powershell script to repeatedly call the batch file and install Java on any system that it finds without the latest version. It seems to run error-free, but the statements inside the if code block never seem to run - even when the if conditional test evaluates to true. Can anyone look at this script and point out what I'm possibly missing? I'm using the Quest AD cmdlets, and BSOnPosh module. Thank you.

```
get-qadcomputer -sizelimit 0 -name mypc* -searchroot 'OU=MyComputers,DC=MyDomain,DC=lcl'| test-host -property name |ForEach-Object -process {
$targnm = $_.name
$tststr=reg query "\\$targnm\HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v Java6FamilyVersion
 if(-not ($tststr | select-string -SimpleMatch '1.6.0_20'))
 {
  $mssg="Updating to JRE 6u20 on $targnm"
  Out-Host $mssg
  Out-File -filepath c:\install_jre_log.txt -inputobject $mssg -Append
  cmd /c \\server\apps\java\installjreremote.cmd $targnm
 }
 else
 {
  $mssg ="JRE 6u20 found on $targnm"
  Out-Host $mssg
  Out-File -filepath c:\install_jre_log.txt -inputobject $mssg -Append
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I've been tinkering with this one for a bit and got it working. At first, it looked like the script was running as expected, except that it would show an error message in the console whenever the reg query command didn't find the reg key that it was looking for. That in itself was not an issue, but after that I would have expected it to continue and run the `if` code block - instead it seemed to be skipping right on to processing the next object in the `foreach-object` queue from the pipeline. I am not sure what was going on there, but eventually I got the code to the point where it was evaluating everything correctly and trying to run the `if` code block. This time, I was getting the following error whenever the script hit an `Out-Host` statement: `Out-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument mystringvar`. Apparently there is something about using `Out-Host` that causes `ForEach-Object` to think that the processing code block is done. Anyway, I overcame this by switching to using `Write-Output` instead. Here's the final working code:

```
import-module bsonposh
add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

get-qadcomputer -sizelimit 0 -searchroot 'OU=MyComputers,DC=MyDomain,DC=lcl' | test-host -property name |ForEach-Object -process {
    $targnm = $_.name
    $tststr=(reg query "\\$targnm\HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v Java6FamilyVersion)
    if(-not($tststr |select-string -simplematch '1.6.0_20'))
    {
        $mssg="Updating to JRE 6u20 on $targnm"
        Write-Output $mssg
        Out-File -filepath c:\install_jre_log.txt -inputobject $mssg -Append
        cmd /c \\myfileserver\apps\java\installjreremote.cmd $targnm
    }
    else
    {
        $mssg ="JRE 6u20 found on $targnm"
        Write-Output $mssg
        Out-File -filepath c:\install_jre_log.txt -inputobject $mssg -Append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try simplifying the `if` to:

```
if($tststr -notmatch '1.6.0_20')
```

to see if that helps, but I don't see anything obviously wrong unless it's never really evaluating to true. So the `else` clause is always run?

Comment: That's not the same as in the question since you're now doing a regular expression match and need to escape the `.` – `-like` might be an appropriate alternative.

Comment: -notlike would work if I were just looking at a simple String, but the reg.exe command actually returns an array of strings. So, I stuck to my original Select-String usage.